# How to delete polygons on Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, polygon

I am displaying polygons every time specific region is selected from drop down using this function:

```
function drawPolygon(polygons) {

 polygons.forEach(function(p) {

 bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: p,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
   })
}
```

How could I remove the last displayed polygon on selecting a new one from the drop down?

Answer (score 0):

Set then `map` property to null.

```
bermudaTriangle.setMap(null);
```

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, 'click', function() {this.setMap(null);}); is partially solving the issue when you click on the polygon. But how to make it such that event is the select of an option from the drop down? Thank you for your help